# Create a function in the global scope in an if block

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.2

I'm writing a PS profile that I'm hoping to use across multiple computers.

In this profile, I'm including a few utility functions.

However, I know that sometimes, a module that I one of those functions depdnds on will ont be available, and so I'd like to not create it.

An example of such a function:

```
if(Get-Module -Name Posh-Git -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Import-Module posh-git

    function global:Push-GitBranch() 
    {
        git push --set-upstream origin (Get-GitStatus).Branch
    }
}
```

However, when I use this profile, the function is not available.
It however is when I define it outside of the if block.

Is it at all possible ? Or should I just add a condition in my function to display a message if a dependency was not found ?

Comment: If fails because `Get-Module` only returns already-imported modules by default. Add the `-ListAvailable` swith parameter to the `Get-Module` call and it'll work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a chicken-and-egg problem:

- `Get-Module posh-git` only returns a valid module info object once posh-git has already been imported
- You only `Import-Module posh-git` once that happens

Add the `-ListAvailable` switch parameter to the `Get-Module` call to discover modules that are available for import:

```
if(Get-Module -Name Posh-Git -ListAvailable -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    Import-Module posh-git

    function global:Push-GitBranch() 
    {
        git push --set-upstream origin (Get-GitStatus).Branch
    }
}
```

---

As [zett42 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73826237/create-a-function-in-the-global-scope-in-an-if-block/73826772#comment130361260_73826772) you could even get rid of the `Get-Module` call altogether: just attempt to import the module and see if it succeeds:

```
if(Import-Module posh-git -PassThru -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
{
    # posh-git is definitely imported by now
    function global:Push-GitBranch() 
    {
        git push --set-upstream origin (Get-GitStatus).Branch
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I forgot that `Get-Module` only returned the loaded ones. And good alternative suggestion, should save some time at start.